# Woodin's theorem about the existence of sharps for the Chang's model

Tags: reference-request, lo.logic, set-theory

In [The sharp for the Chang model is small](http://dracontium.org/wp-content/uploads/publications/changmodel-paper.pdf), Mitchell has stated a result of Woodin about the Chang's model, and he has produced a  result using much weaker assumptions.

As it is stated in the paper, the result proved by Mitchell is weaker than Woodin's result. I refer to Section 1.1 of the paper for the comparison of the results of Mitchell and Woodin.

> I am wondering if anyone knows how Woodin's theorem is proved, and if there are any proofs of it available.